# Format the output of cputime for ps

Tags: bash, ps, text-formatting

I'm trying to write a script that can monitor a process's CPU usage over an interval (to create a graph).

So far, this is the command I'm using

```
ps -p $PROCID -o cputime,etimes
```

My only concern is that the output of cputime appears to be `[dd]hh:mm` (or something similar, can't remember off the top of my head now)

Is there a way to format cputime in seconds, kind of like etime -> etimes to get elapsed time in seconds?

Edit: This is the output that I'm currently receiving

```
2-03:01:33 2653793
```

I'd like the first parameter to be formatted in seconds, not days-hours:minutes:seconds.

Comment: can you please add the output you receive now and the output you'd like to receive?

Comment: @Simply_Me I have edited the post

Comment: @John1024 Yes, it is, that's the amount of days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This converts the first time to seconds:

```
ps -p $PROCID -o cputime,etimes | awk -F'[: ]+' '/:/ {t=$3+60*($2+60*$1); print t,$NF}'
```

As an example, the ps command produces:

```
$ ps -p 5403 -o cputime,etimes
    TIME ELAPSED
01:33:38 1128931
```

The `awk` command processes that and returns:

```
ps -p 5403 -o cputime,etimes | awk -F'[: ]+' '/:/ {t=$3+60*($2+60*$1); print t,$NF}'
5618 1128931
```

#### Explanation

- `-F'[: ]+'`

  This tells awk to treat both colons and spaces as field separators.  This way, the hours, minutes, and seconds appear as separate fields.
- `/:/ {t=$3+60*($2+60*$1); print t,$NF}`

  The initial `/:/` restricts the code to working only on lines that include a colon.  This removes the header lines.  The number of seconds is calculated from hours, minutes, seconds via `t=$3+60*($2+60*$1)`.  The resulting value for `t` is then printed along side with the elapsed time.

#### Handling days

If `ps` produces days,hours,minutes,seconds, as in:

```
2-03:01:33
```

Then, use this code instead:

```
ps -p $PROCID -o cputime,etimes | awk -F'[-: ]+' '/:/ {t=$4+60*($3+60*($2+24*$1)); print t,$NF}'
```

If days may or may not be prepended to the output, then use this combination command:

```
ps -p $PROCID -o cputime,etimes | awk -F'[-: ]+' '/:/ && NF==5 { t=$4+60*($3+60*($2+24*$1)); print t,$NF} /:/ && NF==4 {t=$3+60*($2+60*$1); print t,$NF}'
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but it doesn't look like this command is taking into account days, which can also be prepended

Comment: That is correct: my system did not show days for any process.  I can guess what days might look like, but can you provide an actual example?

Comment: 2-03:01:33 is 2 days, 3 hours, 1 minute, and 33 seconds. Days doesn't always get prepended though. On my system it's only prepended if the process has been alive for more than 24 hours. Thanks for your help so far btw, I appreciate it

Comment: @user1772510 Answer updated to handle days.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, if I could upvote I'd upvote as well (not enough rep in this community) I appreciate it deeply!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to bring awk in the game, a pure bash solution (t_str contains the formated string, t_sec the decoded time in seconds):

```
# Decode the CPU time format [dd-]hh:mm:ss.
IFS="-:" read c1 c2 c3 c4 <<< "$t_str"
if [ -n "$c4" ]
then
  t_sec=$((10#$c4+60*(10#$c3+60*(10#$c2+24*10#$c1))))
else
  t_sec=$((10#$c3+60*(10#$c2+60*10#$c1)))
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which operating system this is for; if it is Linux, and given that you're interested in monitoring a specific process, you might find it more worthwhile to parse `/proc/$PROCID/stat` - see the `proc(5)` manual page for details.